# How can I load a script in a script tag dynamically

Tags: electron

I want to run a script attandancechecker.js from index.html file, but my method isn't working. How can I run it?

Here is my code example

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>
  <script src="preload.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Login to Your App</h1>
  <form id="loginForm">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    if (typeof window.myAPI !== 'undefined') { // Check for myAPI object
      document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const username = event.target.username.value;
        const password = event.target.password.value;

        try {
          const response = await window.myAPI.invoke('login', { username, password });
          if (response === 'success') {
            console.log('Login successful');
            window.myAPI.send('login-success'); // Use window.myAPI to send the event
          } else {
            console.log('Login failed');
            // Show error message or take appropriate action
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error occurred during login:', error);
          // Handle the error, show an error message, etc.
        }
      });

      // Listen for the 'login-success' event using the exposed function
      window.myAPI.onLoginSuccess(() => {
        console.log('Login success event received');
        const attendanceScript = document.createElement('script');
        attendanceScript.src = 'attendancechecker.js';
        attendanceScript.onload = () => {
          console.log('Attendance checker script loaded.');
          // Now you can perform your attendance checking logic
        };
        document.body.appendChild(attendanceScript);
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

my preload.js

```js
import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron';


contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI', {
  invoke: (channel, ...args) => ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, ...args),
  send: (channel, ...args) => ipcRenderer.send(channel, ...args),
  onLoginSuccess: (listener) => {
    ipcRenderer.on('login-success', listener);
  },
  
});
```

This is the method that I implemented in main.js

```js
ipcMain.handle('login', (event, loginData) => {
  const { username, password } = loginData;
  // Perform your login logic here
  const isValidUser = true;

  if (isValidUser) {
    // If the login is successful, load the main app page
    mainWindow.loadURL('http:some_url/?access_token=my_token');
    mainWindow.show();
    console.log("success event retured");
    return 'success';
  } else {
    // If the login fails, show an error or take appropriate action
    console.log("failure event retured");
    return 'failure';
  }
});
```

I know I'm giving hardcoded token, but it's only for testing purposes.

This is my browserWindow function.

```js
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      webSecurity: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      
    },
  });
```

I tried this method

```js
window.myAPI.onLoginSuccess(() => {
        console.log('Login success event received');
        const attendanceScript = document.createElement('script');
        attendanceScript.src = 'attendancechecker.js';
        attendanceScript.onload = () => {
          console.log('Attendance checker script loaded.');
          // Now you can perform your attendance checking logic
        };
        document.body.appendChild(attendanceScript);
      });
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I also tried ES module export for my attandancecheker.js, but that does not seem to work either.

I want that on successful login, my attendance script should run only after on login, but in my attandacechecker.js script I have this method

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  console.log("Page loaded"); // Add this line to confirm page loading
  checkAttendanceAndOpenApp();
  setInterval(checkAttendanceAndOpenApp, 60000);
});
```

which should run my function every minute.